# Android: Get the element triggering an onclick event

Tags: android, dynamic, onclick

Here is my Code:

```
ImageButton ibtnCherry;
ImageButton ibtnSelected;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup);

    ibtnCherry = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibtnCherry);

    ibtnCherry.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ibtnSelected = ??????????;
    Intent sdintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    sdintent.setType("image/*");
    sdintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(sdintent, GlobaleVariablen.SD_REQUEST);
}
```

My Problem is, that I need something like "ibtnSelected = ibtnCherry" in the row with the questionmarks, but dynamically, so when another button (e.g. ibtnTmp) fires the same onClick event, ibtnTmp is saved in ibtnSelected.

Is there any chance to get the element in the onClick event that fires it?

Comment: Do you know what the view parameter in onClick is?

Comment: oh... *facepalm* sry guys.... i thought i know it and searched something like "view.getElement()". But its "(ImageView)view" ... thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should have looked up the onclick method declaration from the docs, nothing else ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ibtnSelected = view;` that is enough. :-)

Comment: Addendum: Set up a check like `if (view.getID() == R.id.ibtnCherry) { <doYourStuff> }` to avoid surprises if your program evolves to a point where more than one view has this OnClickListener set.

Comment: You should cast the View to ImageButton `ibtnSelected = (ImageButton)view`